# How can an unlimited adversary distinguish PRF's from Truly Random Functions (TRF)?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

I'd like to know which strategy is adopted by an unlimited adversary to distinguish PRF's from Truly Random Functions

Comment: Yes, truly random function

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Is this homework? If so, please write it in the question and show your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first define the domain and range of the function we want to distinguish to be $M = \{0,1\}^m$ and $N = \{ 0,1\}^n$.

Now, what does it mean for a function to be truly random? It means that it was selected uniformly at random from the space $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$, which consists of *all* functions from $M$ to $N$. How many such functions are there? I.e., how big is the space $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$? Answer: $N^M = 2^{n \cdot 2^m}$ (exercise: prove this).

On the other hand, if the function is a PRF, then it was not drawn from the full space $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$, but rather from a much smaller space indexed by the key of the PRF. That is, a PRF is formally a *family* of functions $\{F_k \}_{k \in K}$, where each member is a function $F_k \colon M \to N$. What we really mean when we say that the function is a PRF, is that we first pick a key $k \in K$ uniformly at random from the key space, and then we use the function $F_k$ indexed by this key to answer all queries. So how big is the PRF "function space"? It's simply the size of the key space $K$, i.e., $|K|$.

In the PRF distinguishing game we are then asked to distinguish a function which is either randomly selected from the set $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$, or randomly selected from the family $\{F_k \}_{k \in K}$. For concreteness, suppose $M = N = K = \{0, 1\}^{128}$. Thus, in this case we are asked to distinguish a function which is either drawn from a set of size $2^{128 \cdot 2^{128}}$, or from a set of size $2^{128}$. Notice the *massive* difference in size between these two sets! The PRF family lives inside a tiny tiny tiny bubble of the whole space $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$. In other words, the functions in the PRF family only exhibits a *very* tiny portion of all possible functional behaviors between the sets $M$ and $N$.

So how can we use this to distinguish whether the function we are given is truly random or only a PRF? Well, since we are an unlimited adversary, we can simply query the function at *all* possible inputs in $M$ to determine exactly which function in $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$ we are dealing with. If the function does not belong to the function family $\{F_k \}_{k \in K}$, then we of course know that it was selected as a truly random function and not as a PRF. But if it *does* belong to $\{F_k \}_{k \in K}$, what should we guess then? I claim that we should guess that the function was selected as a PRF. Why? Well, if the function was selected uniformly at random from $\mathsf{FUNC}(M, N)$, what is the probability that it would happen to coincide with a function in $\{F_k \}_{k \in K}$? Answer: *really* tiny. (Exactly how tiny I leave to you to figure out).

Comment: Is it the ratio between the number of PRF functions(cardinality of the key) and the number of TRF?

Comment: @PippoPluto Yes, exactly.